# Парсинг Яндекс карт

Tags: python, парсер

Всем добра.
Стоит задача в парсинге Яндекс карт:
нужно рассчитывать расстояние между двумя точками (километры, расстояние между городами) и примерное время, за которое, собственно, будет преодолено это расстояние. Буду рад любым рекомендациям и источникам

Использую Python, новичок

Comment: https://yandex.ru/maps-api/

Comment: @AlexeyTen вот только оно стоит как чугунный мост 

Comment: Как вариант - посмотрите в сторону селениума‍♀️